# Deployment and Remote Hosts in PhpStorm + test in localhost

Tags: php, ftp, xampp, phpstorm

I used XAMPP + PhpStorm to develop a small Web application. Files were in `htdocs` folder and database on MySQL. Editor as PhpStorm.

After I have completed the project deployed it to the real server, so far all OK, it works in the real server without an issue.

Whenever I need to make a change in the application I tested it in local server and go CPanel and replace the file. This is what I used to do,
every time I need to change something (even a small CSS changes) I had to use this method.

So when I search a way around for this I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHK20LWEWXQ) where I can use PhpStorm directly with FTP to make changes real time.

So far OK and I see that whenever I made a small change it reflect in the real server.

**My question is:** without affecting the real server first, is there a way where I can test this in my local server? I tried running in `localhost/webapplication` , it returns a blank screen. I thought it would fetch the realtime MySQL DB and work...

Am I doing something wrong? I am new to this, please help. Maybe I am using the tool inefficient.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHK20LWEWXQ
According to this, I have set up the Deployment and Remote Hosts, but now I can not run it in local server, it gives me a blank screen when I try to edit it in my XAMPP server.

Comment: Its almost impossible te answer your question wy you get a blank screen without seeing any code. But, on many server I work on (With DirectAdmin) the database only allow connections from the server itself. I have to add my IP address in direct admin to allow connections also from my IP.

Comment: Even better would be to have also a test database, i never connect my development 
environment to my live database. You can also try to use git in phpstorm, when you push your changes there is also a checkbox to push it directly to your remote host

Comment: @Baracuda078 how can i do that,can you provide me a video link or something so i can learn.thanks,

Comment: On how to use git? or some thing else?

Comment: Are you expecting your local site to get data from a production MySQL server? If not - I can't see how is this different from the time you were developing the site locally. In that case you should look into why your local site copy returns a blank page